# why does method reset not exist?

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5, traits

I am trying reset password, using trait ResetsPasswords, and then I got that method.And I'm tried to change method as `public`

How can I do that?

1. method `ResetPasswordController::reset` does not exist

```
protected function reset(Request $request) {
  $request->validate($this->rules(), $this->validationErrorMessage());
  $response = $this->broker()->reset($this->credentials($request), function($user, $password) {
    $this->resetPassword($user, $password);
  });

  return $response == Password::PASSWORD_RESET
    ? $this->sendResetResponse($request, $response)
    : $this->sendResetFailedResponse($request, $resposne);
}
```

2. `api.php`

```
Route::post('password/reset', 'Api\ResetPasswordController@reset');
```

3. this my controller:`ResetPasswordController`

```
class ResetPasswordController extends Controller
{


    protected function sendResetResponse(Request $request,$response)
    {
        return response(['message:' => trans($response)]);
    }

    protected function sendResetFailedResponse(Request $request, $response)
    {
        return response(['error:' => trans($response)], 402);
    }


}
```

Comment: maybe you should use `public` instead of `protected`

Comment: @4givN oh but it’s trait